# Uipath offline packages install

Tags: uipath

How do you add the Microsoft word activities to a uipath installation that is offline? V8

I have tried downloading it on an online pc then copying it across to the program files. No joy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Installing the packages from "\Program Files (x86)\UiPath Studio\Packages" is one way. You can also configure other sources for .nupkg installation.

1. Click on 'Manage Packages'. Right click on left side of window and select 'Configure Sources'.

[image]

2. Click on Add (+) and select the folder where .nupkg are stored.
3. Give the name for the source. Then you can access all .nupkg in that folder.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Transfer the .nupkg to "\Program Files (x86)\UiPath Studio\Packages"
2. In UiPath Studio -> Activities -> Manage Packages -> Available you should find it and click install.

Note: The Word package has a DocX dependency. That .nupkg should be copied also.